# Orbeon cache headers

Tags: orbeon

I'm running orbeon 3.70beta and I need to avoid cache. In particular I need orbeon to return in the http response the following attributes:

```
Cache-Control=max-age=0  
Pragma=no-cache  
Expires=0
```

I tried this properties on the properties.xml :

```
<property as="xs:string"
      name="oxf.http.page.cache-headers"
      value="Cache-Control: max-age=0; Pragma: no-cache; Expires: 0"/>

<property as="xs:string"
      name="oxf.http.resource.cache-headers"
      value="Cache-Control: max-age=0; Pragma: no-cache; Expires: 0"/>
```

But I'm still getting a response like this:

```
Cache-Control:public
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:772
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 20 Jul 2012 13:14:18 GMT
Expires:Fri, 20 Jul 2012 13:14:18 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 20 Jul 2012 13:00:51 GMT
Pragma:
Server:WebSphere Application Server/6.1

Note:
Also I add a filter in the web.xml and add the compiled filter but it 
seems that orbeon is overriding the cache headers in some point.

Note2:
I already override the cache headers on other application (using a filter) in the 
same websphere and the headers are successfully overridden. So the Websphere 
is not the problem.
```

I will appreciate the help very much.

Thanks,
Francisco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These properties were added for Orbeon Forms 4.0 so they won't work with 3.7. (3.7.1 is more than 3 years old, and the 3.7.0beta build you are using is probably even older.) Your best bet is to do this by using a servlet filter like [UrlRewriteFilter](https://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) or a front-end HTTP server like Apache.

Comment: Hi!

 Thank you very much for the reply. 

  **I think a filter is not an option since I did one myself** and It didn't work. If I put the filter before the processing (before the chain.doFilter(...)) orbeon override those parameters and if I put it after, orbeon already flush the headers to the client and an error is prompted. Do you think I'm missing something and I could use this approach?.

  **I will go with the update to 4.0** and hope it is backward compatible with my 3.7 forms :).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I realize that orbeon 4.0 don't have a property.xml and orbeon 3.7 does. Is this going to affect the behavior? It's a good idea to include the properties that are defined on 3.7 to the 4.0? To make it backward compatible.

Comment: What you are looking for is `properties-local.xml`. See the [doc](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties).

Comment: We had the same problem while trying to use a filter and did not even want to upgrade from 3.9. So instead we made changes to org\orbeon\oxf\servlet\ServletExternalContext.java and recompiled the product